# SQL query.setParameter() not getting single quoted string in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I am trying to run one SQL query using indexed query as,
    list.add("'%" + some_string + "%'");
 and set in query(sample) like :

```
query=select * from table where name like ?1;
```

I am setting parameter as :

```
 query.setParameter(1, list.get(0));
```

It doesn't work, instead if I put the value directly in query, like :

```
select * from table where name like '%"+some_string+"%'
```

It works. I am using JPA Hibernate and postgres database.

Is there any internal parsing of single quotes while setting parameter as

query.setParameter();

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `''` quotes from the placeholder value being added to the `List`.

```
list.add("%" + some_string + "%");
```

Now `query.setParameter(1, list.get(0));` should work as expected because any string value being bound to a `?` placeholder does not require to be quoted.

Comment: I did that..was working fine! But just worried because I am using LIKE in query which takes parameter in single quotes!

Comment: It has nothing to do with LIKE as such. If you had been using any other operator like = or an IN clause, it would still require unquoted string values as parameters for your prepared statement.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal How to set parameter in such a way that the single quotes don't get added? I need to pass a column name as a parameter. Can't put the column name as "+ columnName +" 'cause I fetch the query from a JSON. Any ideas?